# Nearby Messages: AudioBytes not being received

Tags: android, google-nearby

Google Play Services 10.2 includes AudioBytes: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_v102

As I understand it, it's a message that can be transmitted directly from one device to another using ultrasonics, instead of routing the payload over the Internet as Nearby Messages usually does.

Documentation is nearly nonexistent: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/audio/AudioBytes

But I puzzled out that I should try:

```
AudioBytes audioBytes = new AudioBytes("Hello".getBytes());
Message message = audioBytes.toMessage();
Nearby.Messages.publish(googleApiClient, message);
```

As near as I can tell, the main difference is that it changes the `type` of the Message. The problem is, I my subscribing code never receives Messages created with AudioBytes, although it does receive regular Messages just fine. The publishing and subscribing phones are right next to each other physically, and their speakers and microphones are functional.

The only other reference I can find online to AudioBytes is https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/5vlt9r/anyone_have_luck_with_nearby_messagings_audiobytes/, which is someone else saying they can't get it working.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is AudioBytes just broken?

Comment: Same for me. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: I never found a solution, but I haven't tried since around the time of this post, and haven't heard anyone discuss it.